# Why do you plan to change the default IFC Model Derivative processor from Navisworks importer to Revit importer?

Tags: autodesk-forge

In this article

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/model-derivative-ifc-pipeline-call-change

is described that you are planing to change the IFC Model Derivative processor previously based on the Navisworks importer to the Revit based importer.

The Revit based IFC translation pipeline:

- is slower, it takes up to five times longer than the legacy IFC loader
- it does not interpret all information written in the IFC file (for example custom psets)
- it crashes while opening large ifc files

Why are you planing to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is from our Engineering:

> In theory the Revit based IFC translation pipeline gives higher quality results. However, there might be some missing properties and it certainly is a lot slower. But the upside is we just have one IFC codebase to fix issues in. We are aware of the performance issues and are investigating our options.

Will continue to discuss these options with Engineering and update this answer with updates.

Comment: Recommendation: 

If someone uploads the files programmatically with the legacy Navisworks importer. 
Make sure, that you are waiting for the right translation job. 

Newly there are two jobs triggered at the same point. The Revit based translation (comes automatically) and the Navis based translation (that’s what you actually need).
Make sure, that you are waiting only for the Navis based translation, because the Revit translation takes way longer.

Example:
dynamic manifest = await derivativeApi.GetManifestAsync(urn);
progress = manifest.derivatives[0].children[0].progress;